# React sending data from one component to another one

Tags: reactjs

This is a function on my Login component page and `result.user` when user logs in successfully responds with user information. How can I send the `result.user` information to my main page, so I can set what a user can and can't do?

```
newLogin = (e) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.user)
        });
}
```

Comment: You would typically invoke a callback that was passed as a prop from a parent component to the login component, or maybe dispatch a redux action to store it in app state that the other component is subscribed to, or maybe your app is using the React Context API. Can you provide a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of the relationship between these two components?

Comment: Create a piece of state in your main file and the pass it down as props. Then using the `setUser` (let's say) function, you can set the user to `result.user`. Now you have it in your main file in the `user` variable.

Comment: You can use context, redux, localstorage what you actually want ;) Read about good practices to store user information in security way ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of your components but You should use `react-redux` to store your logged-in user because this data is needed to access anywhere in your application and in any component, I highlyl recommend to you to use `react-redux` for your best practice.

React-redux is easy to use and easy to access any logged-in user's data from the state, so it's better to approach to use `react-redux` instead of passing data through props.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `localStorage` to store the data in the browser. in which you can store the data and can use it in anywhere of your code. you don't need to pass the data. when the user log out you need to clear the sorage.
**To craete a element in storage**

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', 'result.user')
```

**To clear the data when user logout**

```
localStorage.removeItem('userData');
```

here `userData` is representing data stored in the browser.
you can check each time when you needed ,so that whether the user is still logged in using

```
localStorage.getItem('userData');
```

if userData is available then you can consider that user is logged in.

Comment: I've thought about this can work. But isn't there a better way to connect my reactjs frontend and nodejs rather than having to save user data in localstorage? 

Because at the same time when somebody is to buy my product, I need to update their backend database aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for managing user login in react apps is to use state management for those like Redux and Mobx, you can use React.Context which is easy to use.
In one case I created a wrapper for React.Context.
[React-principal](https://github.com/hosseinmd/react-principal)
In another case, I created a state management which is so much easier to use [react-global-hook](https://github.com/hosseinmd/react-global-hook)